# Razor Page - How to redirect to another folder's page using asp-for tag helper

Tags: asp.net, razor, asp.net-core-2.0

I've been having issues with this but I think is simple.

asp.net core 2.0 Razor Pages

I have a Users/index page and I added a link to take me to the child records under Entries Folder.

Structure is like 
Pages
/Users
/Entries

Under /Pages/Users/index.cshtml

```
 <a asp-page="./Edit" asp-route-id="@item.Id">Edit</a> |
   <a asp-page="./Details" asp-route-id="@item.Id">Details</a>|
   <a asp-page="~/Pages/Entries/" asp-route-id="@item.Id">Enter Child Records</a>
```

However, on the browser, looks like is not rendering the correct link. It staying under the default page.

I tried `asp-page="../Entries/"` and other combinations with no luck.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Can't believe this but this works.

```
<a asp-page="../Entries/Index" asp-route-id="@item.Id">test</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your own answer might add confusions to others. First of all, you're talking about LINKs to another page, not redirect to another page. Razor Pages have a designated function for page redirections.

About the **asp-page** tag helper, it's interpreted by the code-behind engine (e.g. C# syntax) and so the "~" doesn't work. Basically, asp-page is expecting a name. In your own examples:

```
<a asp-page="./Edit" asp-route-id="@item.Id">Edit</a> |
<a asp-page="./Details" asp-route-id="@item.Id">Details</a>|
```

will work, but they should be **shortened** as:

```
<a asp-page="Edit" ...>Edit</a> |
<a asp-page="Details" ...>Details</a>|
```

because they are in the same folder as your /Users/Index page. As you know the "**./**" part just means going up one level to your parent folder and so it's redundant. You don't want to instruct your engine to go up one level and then come down again to the same folder immediately.

When you need to switch to another containing folder, going up two levels and specify the new folder name. So, the "**../NewFolder**" works.

If it is at the web site root level, you can use the root syntax directly for faster routing. So both of these work the same if **AnotherFolder** is under **root**:

```
<a asp-page="../AnotherFolder/Index" ...>test</a>
<a asp-page="/AnotherFolder/Index" ...>test</a>
```

The **asp-page** tag helper is expecting a **real page name** at the last part and hence the quoted text must be ended with a page name. You **cannot** use asp-page="**/Entries/**" as in HTML URLs and expect the engine to default to Index page for you.

Lastly, to cover redirecting pages, code-behind has a function called return **RedirectToPage(string pageName, ...)**, and its first parameter uses the same page routing syntax as the asp-page tag helper described above.

There is also a **Redirect()** function that works with pages outside your Razor Pages system, which can take any URLs as your browser or HTML code do. That's another story.